# Queue ordering

Tags: c#, queue

I have an array of items, sorted so that the oldest item is first in the array.

I want to load a queue from the array, such that when I pop the items on the queue the oldest item comes first.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7):

Use LINQ to Objects...

```
var q = new Queue<T>(array.OrderBy(d => d.date));
```

EDIT: Ops, wrong way around.

Comment: According to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/69zckb8z.aspx it takes an IEnumerable<T>.

Answer (score 2):

If you know that your array is already sorted oldest-first then you can use:

```
Queue<YourType> q = new Queue<YourType>(yourSortedArray);
```

If the array isn't pre-sorted then you can sort it using LINQ:

```
Queue<YourType> q =
    new Queue<YourType>(yourUnsortedArray.OrderBy(x => x.YourDateProperty));
```

Then you can just call `q.Dequeue` to get the items in oldest-to-newest order.

Comment: Are you sure you need to reverse the array?

Comment: @teedyay, Thanks, corrected! I did actually test this too, just read the results wrong. :(

Answer (score 2):

You want a [priority queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue). Then it doesn't matter whether your incoming items are sorted or not.

Maybe there is an implementation in the library.

PS: the *priority* in your case would map to *age*.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public static T ArrayToQueue<T>(T[] items) {
  var queue = new Queue<T>();
  Array.ForEach(items, i => queue.Enqueue(i));
  return queue;
}
```